# Can Optaplanner handle the Dial-A-Ride Problem (aka Uber Pooling)?

Tags: optaplanner

Optaplanner looks like it's great at Vehicle Routing for problems involving single entities, such as a taxi fleet of taxis transporting single customers between locations.

But what about more complex systems where the vehicle is shared by multiple people at once, such as DARP or Uber pooling where it could like something like:

```
Pick up customer 1 -> Pick up customer 2 -> Drop off customer 1 -> Pick up customer 3 -> Drop off customer 2 -> Drop off customer 3
```

As per the description of DARP:

> The Dial-a-Ride Problem (DARP) consists of designing vehicle routes and schedules for n users who specify pickup and delivery requests between origins and destinations. The aim is to plan a set of m minimum cost vehicle routes capable of accommodating as many users as possible, under a set of constraints. The most common example arises in door-to-door transportation for elderly or disabled people.

Is this sort of thing possible with Optaplanner?

I looked through the documentation to grasp what Optaplanner could do, but not too sure where its limits lie at.

Answer (score 0):

In theory, doing a mixed VRP in OptaPlanner is possible. In practice, we have not yet gotten around to finding the best possible model which we could recommend to users.

We have an old [JIRA for it](https://issues.redhat.com/projects/PLANNER/issues/PLANNER-833) where some proposals were outlined, but no definitive conclusion was reached.